# Can we do a bulk index without specifying a document ID for Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to do a bulk index without specifying a document ID? I want Elasticsearch to generate a random ID for me while indexing, but can it be done?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes you can!

Tested on 0.90.0.Beta1:

```
$ cat requests 
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }

$ curl -s -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary @requests; echo
{"took":6,"items":[{"create":{"_index":"test","_type":"type1","_id":"IWqsRqyhRVq-F69OLIngTA","_version":1,"ok":true}}]}
```

Comment: Can you please provide the sample JAVA API for the same operation by script?

Comment: Thanks, @dadoonet . Is it possible to update multiple documents without specifying an id?

Comment: Not with the bulk API. Update by query is may be what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another example of bulk upload without specifying the _id.

`

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/_bulk" -d'
    { "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "demo" } }
    { "title" : "Quick brown rabbits", "content" : "Brown rabbits are commonly seen" }
    { "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "demo" } }
    { "title" : "Keeping pets healthy", "content" : "My quick brown fox eats rabbits
```

`

Response is below

`

```
{
  "took": 451,
  "errors": false,
  "items": [
    {
      "create": {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "demo",
        "_id": "AVYDtp_fxosF2Bdj7ghV",
        "_version": 1,
        "_shards": {
          "total": 2,
          "successful": 1,
          "failed": 0
        },
        "status": 201
      }
    },
    {
      "create": {
        "_index": "test",
        "_type": "demo",
        "_id": "AVYDtp_fxosF2Bdj7ghW",
        "_version": 1,
        "_shards": {
          "total": 2,
          "successful": 1,
          "failed": 0
        },
        "status": 201
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

`

Comment: not able to use this trick , it says :  "type": "action_request_validation_exception",
                "reason": "Validation Failed: 1: an id must be provided if version type or value are set;"